# Visual Studio SCC API - programmatically checkout files

Tags: visual-studio-2013, version-control, visual-studio-shell

Is there a generic programmatic way to use the Visual Studio Source Control Plugin API to check out files, browse repositories and check in files?

I am aware that I can use the TFS API to acheive the same results. However I would like to be able to execute source control commands generically enough without having to worry about which source control is currently used (TFS, SVN, git .. etc)
Note: I am using a Visual Studio package to develop that. So I am in a VS Shell environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As all SCM systems are built by different vendors there is no such abstraction later. You will need to create custom code for each system and make sure that each systems API is available to do so.

Comment: I believe that the providers are still specific to the target. And you can only do very simple operations.